# Localisation is isomorphic to a quotient of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

I am having trouble with the following problem.

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $a \in R$ be a non-zero element. Let $D = \{1, a, a^2, ...\}$. I need to show that $R_D \cong R[x]/(ax-1)$.

I just want a hint.

Basically, I've been looking for a surjective homomorphism from $R[x]$ to $R_D$, but everything I've tried has failed. I think the fact that $f(a)$ is a unit, where $f$ is our mapping, is relevant, but I'm not sure. Thanks

Comment: To be clear, this holds for any commutative ring $R$, and $a \in R$ can be any element. (See the answer of Maxime)

Answer (score 31):

You can use the **universal properties**, namely, the **universal property of the localization**, of the **polynomial ring**, and of the **quotient**.

Recall that if $R$ is a commutative ring and $D$ is a multiplicative subset, there is a homomorphism $\phi\colon R\to R_D$, given by $\phi(r) = \frac{rd}{d}$ (where $d\in D$ is arbitrary); this map is well-defined, and has the *universal property*:

> If $T$ is any ring, and $f\colon R\to T$ is a ring homomorphism with the property that $f(d)$ is a unit in $T$ for each $d\in D$, then there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\mathcal{F}\colon R_D\to T$ such that $\mathcal{F}\circ\phi = f$.

Consider the natural embedding $R\to R[x]$ followed by the quotient map $R[x]\to R[x]/(ax-1)$. Call this $f$. Note that $f(a)$ is a unit in $R[x]/(ax-1)$, hence so are $f(a^n)$ for every $n$. Therefore, every element of $D$ is mapped to a unit in $R[x]/(ax-1)$, which means that there is a unique homomorphism $\mathcal{F}\colon R_D\to R[x]/(ax-1)$ with the property that $\mathcal{F}\circ \phi = f$.

The claim is that $\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism.

To establish this, we construct an inverse. The universal property of the polynomial ring $R[x]$ tells us that if we specify how to map $R$ and what element we want $x$ to map to, we get a homomorphism. We define a homomorphism $R[x]\to R_D$ by mapping the coefficient ring $R$ to $R_D$ using $\phi$, and mapping $x$ to $\frac{1}{a}\in R_D$. This gives us a homomorphism $g\colon R[x]\to R_D$.

Now, the polynomial $ax-1$ is mapped to $0$: $g(ax-1) = \phi(a)\frac{1}{a}-\phi(1) = \frac{aa}{a}\frac{1}{a} - \frac{a}{a} = 0_{R_D}$, so by the universal property of the quotient, the map $g$ factors through $R[x]/(ax-1)$. That is, there is a unique homomorphism $\mathcal{G}\colon R[x]/(ax-1)\to R_D$ such that $g = \mathcal{G}\circ \pi$, where $\pi\colon R[x]\to R[x]/(ax-1)$ is the canonical projection.

So now we have homomorphism $\mathcal{F}\colon R_D\to R[x]/(ax-1)$ and $\mathcal{G}\colon R[x]/(ax-1)\to R_D$. I claim that $\mathcal{G}$ is the inverse of $\mathcal{F}$.

First, consider
$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
&&R&&\\
&{\small\phi}\swarrow & {\small f}\downarrow&\searrow{\small\phi}\\
R_D & \stackrel{\mathcal{F}}{\to} & \frac{R[x]}{(ax-1)} &\stackrel{\mathcal{G}}{\to} & R_D
\end{array}$$
Now, notice that $\mathcal{G}f=\phi$, since elements of $R$ in $R[x]$ are mapped to $R_D$ as $\phi$. So this diagram commutes; that is, $\mathcal{GF}\phi =\mathrm{id}_{R_D}\phi$. But the universal property of the localization says that there is a unique map $R_D\to R_D$ that makes the diagram
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
&R&\\
{\small\phi}\swarrow  &&\searrow{\small\phi}\\
R_D & \longrightarrow& R_D
\end{array}$$
commute; clearly the identity does, but we just saw that $\mathcal{GF}$ does as well. That means that we must have $\mathcal{GF} = \mathrm{id}_{R_D}$.

On the other hand, consider the composition $\mathcal{FG}\colon R[x]/(ax-1)\to R[x]/(ax-1)$. The restriction to (the image of) $R$ of this map is just 
$$\mathcal{FG}(\pi(r)) = \mathcal{F}(g(r)) = \mathcal{F}(\phi(r)) = f(r) = r+(ax-1)$$ (where $(ax-1)$ means the ideal of $R$, not the element $ax-1$). And the image of the class of $x$ is $$\mathcal{FG}(\pi(x)) = \mathcal{F}(g(x)) = \mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) = f(a)^{-1} = x+(ax-1).$$ So the map $\mathcal{FG}$ agrees with the identity on $\pi(R)$ and on $\pi(x)$, hence equals the identity. So $\mathcal{FG}=\mathrm{id}_{R[x]/(ax-1)}$.

Thus, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{G}^{-1}$, so $\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism.

---

**Added.** As an alternative of the latter part: once we know that $\mathcal{GF}=\mathrm{id}_{R_D}$, we conclude that $\mathcal{F}$ is one-to-one. Now notice that $\mathcal{F}$ is onto: since $\mathcal{F}\circ \phi = f$, the image of $\mathcal{F}$ contains the image of $f$; the image of $f$ includes the image of all scalars under the projection $R[x]\to R[x]/(ax-1)$. The image of $\mathcal{F}$ also includes the image of $x$, since $\mathcal{F}(\frac{1}{a}) = \mathcal{F}(a)^{-1}$, and the inverse of $\mathcal{F}(a)$ is $x+(ax-1)$. Since $x+(ax-1)$ and $r+(ax-1)$, $r\in R$, generate $R[x]/(ax-1)$, it follows that $\mathcal{F}$ is onto. Since it was already one-to-one, $\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Is it correct just to say that since $\mathcal{G}\circ f=\phi$ and $\mathcal{F}\circ \phi=f$, it follows that $\mathcal{G}\circ\mathcal{F}\circ \phi=\phi$ and $\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{G}\circ f=f$, and the surjectivity of both $\phi$ and $f$ implies $\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{G}=\operatorname{id}$ and $\mathcal{G}\circ\mathcal{F}=\operatorname{id}$?

Comment: Excellent! Dummit and Foote said "It is not difficult to see that." (Example (2) on page 708 in _Abstract Algebra_) You are so good at applying these universal properties. Do you know which books I can find a similar proof?

Comment: Note that this nice proof uses neither that $R$ is an integral domain (any commutative ring would do), nor that $a$ is nonzero.

Comment: @Cary Why is $f$  and $\phi$ surjective?

Answer (score 10):

Here's another answer using the universal property in another way (I know it's a bit late, but is it ever *too* late ?)

As for universal properties in general, the ring satisfying the universal property described by Arturo Magidin in his answer is unique up to isomorphism. Thus to show that $R[x]/(ax-1) \simeq R_D$, it suffices to show that $R[x]/(ax-1)$ has the same universal property !

But that is quite easy: let $\phi: R\to T$ be a ring morphism such that $\phi(a) \in T^{\times}$.

Using the universal property of $R[x]$, we get a unique morphism $\overline{\phi}$ extending $\phi$ with $\overline{\phi}(x) = \phi(a)^{-1}$.

Quite obviously, $ax -1 \in \operatorname{Ker}\overline{\phi}$. Thus $\overline{\phi}$ factorizes uniquely through $R[x]/(ax-1)$.

Thus we get a unique morphism $\mathcal{F}: R[x]/(ax-1) \to T$ with $\mathcal{F}\circ \pi = \phi$, where $\pi$ is the canonical map $R\to R[x]/(ax-1)$. This shows that $\pi: R \to R[x]/(ax-1)$ has the universal property of the localization, thus it is isomorphic to the localization.

This is essentially another way of seeing Arturo Magidin's answer

Comment: Note that this nice proof uses neither that $R$ is an integral domain (any commutative ring would do), nor that $a$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 6):

Define $\phi: R[x] \rightarrow R_D$ by sending $x$ to $1/a$.
We will prove that the kernel of $\phi$ is the ideal of $R[x]$ generated
by $ax -1$.

Let $p\left(x\right) \in \ker \phi$.
Note that $p(x)$ can be naturally viewed as an element of $R_D[x]$.
Since $\phi(p(x))=0$, we have $p(1/a)=0$ in $R_D$. So $1/a$ is a root of $p(x) \in R_D[x]$. Since the leading coefficient of $ax-1$ is a unit in $R_D$, 
Euclidean division applies and
we get that $p(x) = (ax-1) g(x)$ for some $g(x) \in R_D[x]$. Inspecting coefficients on both sides starting from lowest degree terms, we see that in fact $g(x) \in R[x]$ and we are done.

PS: This answer is inspired by Robert Green's answer (and our subsequent interaction) to an identical question that i recently asked, being ignorant of the existence of this post.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "inspecting coefficients on both sides starting from lowest degree terms, we see that in fact $g(x) \in R[x]$"? When I factor out $(ax-1)$ in $R_D[x]$, the lowest-degree terms are too messy to comprehend. If I start with $c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dotsb + c_1x + c_0$, then my coefficients on $g$ are $(c_n/a)x^{n-1} + ((c_{n-1} + c_n/a)/a)x^{n-2}$, and progressively more complicated after that.

Answer (score 4):

In the quotient $R[x]/(ax-1)$, the class of $x$ is invertible. What is its inverse?

This will tell you where $x$ must be mapped under $R[x]\to R_D$ if this must will induce an isomorphism $R[x]/(ax-1)\to R_D$.

Comment: The only nontrivial part of the problem is *proving* that the kernel is $\:(ax-1),\:$ which proves tricky for some.

Comment: @Bill, the question asks for a hint about how to see what the map should be. You are putting the carriage before the horses, as far as I can see...

Comment: The question asks for a hint for a *proof of the isomorphism.* If finding the map proves difficult, then it will probably be a bigger hurdle to verify the kernel *equality* (the necessity of which is often overlooked by students). Hence my emphasis.

Comment: Dear Bill, I suggest you write the answer you have in mind.

Comment: See my hint in comments to Don's answer.

Comment: Well, that is also not writing the answer you have in mind...

Answer (score 3):

As $\,\,ax-1=0\,\,$ in the quotient $\,\,R[x]/(-1+ax)\,\,$, there doesn't seem to be much choice here: the map $$x\to\frac{1}{a}\,\,,\,\,f(x)\to f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)\,,\,f(x)\in R[x]$$

seems like a reasonable choice: it is almost trivial that it is a ring homom. (remember the usual evaluation map), it also is easy to show it is onto $\,R_D\,$ , and its kernel is the ideal it must be.

Comment: *Proving* that the kernel is $(ax-1)$ can be tricky. Did you try it?

Comment: Not really, but seeing that $\,R\,$ is an integral domain, I think we can *slip* into is fractions field and then the proof there goes as usual: a pol. vanishes at some element iff it is divided by the minimal polynomial of that element, which is either $\,ax-1\,$, if there's no demmand of the min. pol. to be monic, or its associate element (in the pol. ring) $\,x-1/a\,$

Comment: That could be circular, since in many presentations this is a precursor to constructing the fraction field (by localization). It can be done without any knowledge of fraction fields.

Comment: How'd you do it? In may case, I'd go by constructing the fractions field in a more elementary way and not as the localization wrt the prime ideal $\,\{0\}\,$ , namely: as the set of equivalence classes of elements of the form $\,a/b\,\,,\,a,b\in R\,\,,\,b\neq 0\,$ under the well-known equiv. relation $\,a/b ~ c/d \Longleftrightarrow ad=bc\,\,in\,\,R$ and the usual operations (this is the way I first learned this, way before I had a commutative algebra course).

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Since the image is a domain, the kernel $\rm\:P\:$ is prime. Note $\rm\ g = ax\!-\!1\in P.\:$ Suppose $\rm\: f \in P.\:$ Hence $\rm\: f + f_0\:\! g =: x\:\!h \in P,\ x \not\in P\Rightarrow\ h\in P.\:$ By induction on degree $\rm\:g\:|\:h\ $ so $\rm\ g\:|\:xh-f_0g = f.\:$ Therefore $\rm\: P = (g) = (ax\!-\!1).\ $ **QED** $\ \ $

Comment: Ok, I'm almost there, but I still can't see why you can assume we can factor out $\,x\,$ in the expression for $\,f+f_0g\,$...? As far as I see, that expression could have a non-zero free doefficient. I can't also see why $\,g\mid h\,$...

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Recall $\rm\:x\:|\:p(x)\iff p(0) = p_0 = 0.\:$ For $\rm\:p = f + f_0 g\:$ we have $\rm\:p_0 = f_0 + f_0 g_0 = f_0 - f_0 = 0.\:$ Thus $\rm\:x\:|\:p,\:$ so $\rm\:p = x\:g,\:$ for some $\rm\:g\in R[x].\:$ Finally $\rm\:g\:|\:h\:$ follows from the (implicit) induction hypothesis, namely that $\rm\:g\:$ divides all elements of $\rm\:P\:$ of smaller degree than $\rm\:f.$

Comment: Oh, wait: I didn't know $\,f_0\,$ mean $\,f(0)\,$ ! Ok, so now it is clear. Why from this $\,g\mid h\,$ though?

Comment: Since $\rm\:h\in P\:$ has smaller degree than $\rm\:f,\:$ our induction hypothesis yields that $\rm\:g\:|\:h.\:$ We are proving by induction on degree that every element $\rm\:f\in P\:$ is divisible by $\rm\:h = ax\!-\!1\in P.\:$

Comment: Oh, thank you. It's nice, yet I think going into the fractions fields is more elementary and easy, but it's always nice to learn new approaches.

Comment: Yes, but only if one already has available a rigorous development of fraction fields. Often this is not done *rigorously* until fraction fields are derived as a special case of localizations. In that case it could be circular to employ fraction fields in proofs about localizations.