# Show $Z(yf-1)$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

Question:

$k$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $f \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Show that $Z(yf-1)\subseteq \textbf{A}^{n+1}$, with coordinates $x_1, \ldots, x_n, y$, is irreducible.

Attempt:

I tried to use the general approach that the set is irreducible iff $(yf-1)$ is a prime ideal iff the coordinate ring is an integral domain, but there has been no concrete progress. I think the main difficulty is I don't know where to use the condition $f$ is irreducible.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do we really need $f$ irreducible?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought $f$ being irreducible is to ensure it's never zero, but in that case $yf \neq 1$. Probably the condition is for the later part (about a morphism induced by projection $\textbf{A}^{n+1} \to \textbf{A}^{n}$).

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by user26857, let's use the fact that the localisation $R_{(f)}$ is isomorphic to $R[y]/(fy - 1)$. If $R_{(f)}$ is an integral domain, then the ideal $(fy - 1)$ is prime.

I leave it to you to prove that $f$ irreducible $\Longrightarrow R_{(f)}$ is an integral domain.

**EDIT**

$R$ is an integral domain, hence $R_{(f)}$ is an integral domain (no need that $f$ is irreducible for that).

Comment: Where $R$ is...?

Comment: My bad, $R := k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ in this case. In fact, $R$ an integral domain should be enough, but I'm too lazy to check that.

Comment: If $R$ is an integral domain, then all its rings of fractions are domains, too. That's why I suggested in a comment under the question that $f$ irreducible is not necessary.

Comment: Indeed, I'll edit my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $R[y]/(ay-1)\simeq R[a^{-1}]$. (For more details see [Localization in a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152236/localization-in-a-ring/152238#152238).)

Comment: Ahh, yes, the [Rabinowitsch trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabinowitsch_trick)