# Units of $R[X]/(aX-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

In the most upvoted answer to another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152236/localisation-is-isomorphic-to-a-quotient-of-polynomial-ring), the author states that:

> $R\to R[x]$ followed by the quotient map $R[x]\to R[x]/(ax-1)$. Call this $f$. Note that $f(a)$ is a unit in $R[x]/(ax-1)$

If I understand correctly, the result is $f(a)=ax^0\mod{ax-1}=ax^0$, and I fail to see why this is necessarily a unit, as $a\in R$ is just a non-zero element in an integral domain, so it doesn't necessarily have an inverse.

Why is $f(a)$ a unit? Am I calculating it wrong?

Comment: Is it just  $f(a) x = 1$, so $x$ is the inverse?

Comment: yes, $f(a)=a+(ax-1)$, so $f(a)x=ax+(ax-1)=1+(ax-1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner could you please explain why $f(a)=a+(ax-1)$? Shouldn't that be divided out and become $f(a)=a$ in the quotient ring?

Comment: Ruben, think about it via $ax=1$ in the quotient ring. Because $ax=1+(ax-1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the ideal $(ax-1) = I$.

The map $f$ sends $a \mapsto a+I$ in the quotient ring and $(x+I)(a+I) = ax+I$ but $-ax+1 \in I$ so $(x+I)(a+I) = 1+I$.

Hence $f(a)$ is a unit in $R[x]/I$.

Comment: Could you please add some detail to the definition of the map $f$? I think I'm understanding it wrong. If $f$ sends $a$ to $a+I$, in the quotient Ring $a+I=a$ right?

Comment: Some people may write $a$ for $a+I$ in the quotient ring (I find this can be slightly misleading) but it is important to remember that in a quotient ring there may be many ways to write the same element. Really $a$ is an element of $R \leqslant R[x]$ but then the quotient map sends $a \mapsto a+I$